# Difference between two consecutive prime numbers

Tags: limits, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ denotes  the $n$-$th$  prime number ,when we enumerate the prime numbers in the increasing order. For example ,$p_1=2,p_2=3,p_3=5$,and so on. Let $S$={${s_n=p_{n+1}-p_n \mid n\in \mathbb{N} ,n\geq 1}$}

> Then $\underline{\lim}_{n \rightarrow\infty}\; s_n \geq 2 $

I know that inf of set $S$ is $1$ ,but how the  $\underline{\lim}_{n \rightarrow}\infty\; s_n \geq 2 $ is possible, as I know  some consecutive  prime that has difference of $2$, but not confirm that there are that much consecutive primes with difference $2$, so that it becomes  limit point.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: There is a proof of this, but it's by a future mathematician.

Comment: I find your question unclear. Of course the limit, if it exists, is larger than 2, as all elements beside $s_1$ are 2 or larger. Or is your question why $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists n \geq N$ so that $s_N = 2$?

Comment: you second line is my question how we come to know that there are that much 2 so that it becomes limit point.

Comment: The question is asking for liminf to be 2, isn't it? And of course that's a notorious open problem.

Comment: yes,but this question is asked in CSIR

Comment: What statement/question? Question about there being no upper limit to $s_n$? or question about the lower limit to $s_n$ perhaps increasing with n? I am having great difficulty understanding your English. With the line under the limit I am assuming second alternative.

Comment: it is inf of lim

Comment: So you are definitely asking about the unsolved twin prime conjecture. Do infinitely many twin primes exist or not? How come then this is a question included in a mathematics syllabus when it is well known to be an open problem with no accepted answer?

Comment: Yes this  is twin conjecture ,i searched it after you comment .  so now the only way to answer  is that i have to assume it without proof.

Comment: @gauravsaini Yes, noone has a proof of the twin prime conjecture, but it is very likely to be true, and I do not think that any mathematician seriously doubts it.